# Loop through rows and when empty move to next column - vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've been spending days in trying to figure out how I need to do this but just can't find it. Hope some one is kind enough to help me out.
The goal of this script is to get a table from a website and put them in a table in Excel.

But I need 6 (For the time being. In the future this will be more than 26 different tables) different tables and I don't want to make a sub for each table request.
So I put all the variable data on Sheet1 of my file.

[image]

The idea is that my script goes over each column and gets the table that I need until there is an empty column. To get this data for 1 column isn't an issue as this is working.
The issue is that I just can't figure out how I can move on to column B, column C, ... until there is an empty column.

I've been trying every single thing that I found online, but nothing seem to get it going. If somebody can help me out or give me clear pointers how to do that would be very much appreciated.

```
Sub ImportTBL1()
    
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim QT As QueryTable
    Dim destCell As Range
    Dim qtResultRange As Range
    Dim TBL As String
    Dim URL As String
    Dim DES As String
    Dim COL As String
    
    Set sourceSheet = Sheet6
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Sheet1!A1")
    Dim cel As Range
        
        For Each cel In rng.Cells
            TBL = rng.Cells(1)
            URL = rng.Cells(2)
            DES = rng.Cells(3)
            COL = rng.Cells(4)
        Next cel
         
    With sourceSheet
        Set destCell = .Range(DES)
        On Error Resume Next
        .ListObjects(TBL).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    Set QT = destCell.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=destCell)
    
    With QT
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .WebFormatting = xlNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = COL
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
        Set qtResultRange = .ResultRange
        .Delete
    End With
    
    With destCell
        .Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TBL
        sourceSheet.ListObjects(TBL).ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What "when empty" does mean? Looking to your code, it looks that it needs only 5 rows and each column has 9 rows. Do you want saying to check the next column after the four values ('TBL, URL, DES, COL') have been used?

Comment: @FaneDuru "when empty" = that there is no data in the rows of this column. So in my example column G has NO data, so there does the script need to stop.

I don't know where you count 5 columns and 9 rows. Check the excel file. There are 6 columns with each 4 rows that have value in them.

I seriously don't know how I can explain this better than I have. The script runs with the data from column A, when this is done it moves over to column B, than column C etc... until it reaches an empty column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just add some context around @FaneDuru's answer and to also help the OP with some understanding about how to approach the problem.

Essentially all you need to do is wrap your code in a `For` loop - as you have a specific task that you want to repeat across independent columns.

In VBA, you have the option of either using a `For Each` loop or a `For Next` loop. Each has their benefits and use and I suppose each could be used in this case. That being said, I would prefer the `For Next` loop because that would mean I no longer need a `Range` object to loop through using the `For Each` approach.

**Approach 1: For Next**

```vb
Sub ImportTBL1()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, QT As QueryTable, destCell As Range
    Dim qtResultRange As Range, TBL As String, URL As String
    Dim DES As String, COL As String
    Dim iCols As Long
    
    Set sourceSheet = Sheet6
    iCols = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    
    For i = 1 To iCols

        TBL = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,i).Value
        URL = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,i).Value
        DES = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,i).Value
        COL = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4,i).Value
             
        With sourceSheet
            Set destCell = .Range(DES)
            On Error Resume Next
            .ListObjects(TBL).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        
        Set QT = destCell.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=destCell)
        
        With QT
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .WebFormatting = xlNone
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = COL
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .Refresh
            Set qtResultRange = .ResultRange
            .Delete
        End With
        
        With destCell
            .Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TBL
            sourceSheet.ListObjects(TBL).ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Approach 2: For Each

```vb
Sub ImportTBL1()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, QT As QueryTable, destCell As Range
    Dim qtResultRange As Range, TBL As String, URL As String
    Dim DES As String, COL As String
    Dim iCols As Long
    
    Set sourceSheet = Sheet6
    iCols = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    Dim rng As Range: cel As Range
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1,iCols))
    End With

    For Each cel in rng
        
        TBL = cel.Value
        URL = cel.Offset(1,0).Value
        DES = cel.Offset(2,0).Value
        COL = cel.Offset(3,0).Value

        With sourceSheet
            Set destCell = .Range(DES)
            On Error Resume Next
            .ListObjects(TBL).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        
        Set QT = destCell.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=destCell)
        
        With QT
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .WebFormatting = xlNone
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = COL
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .Refresh
            Set qtResultRange = .ResultRange
            .Delete
        End With
        
        With destCell
            .Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TBL
            sourceSheet.ListObjects(TBL).ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
        End With
    Next cel
End Sub
```

I have not tested either of the above but you should hopefully get the picture. I will leave it up to you to do further research as to each approach.

Answer (score 0):

You did  not answer the clarification question, but looking at your code I (only suppose) that your code needs only the first 5 rows of each column to be processed. At least, the following code is based on the above described assumption. Please, test it and send some feedback:

```
Sub ImportTBL1()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet, QT As QueryTable, destCell As Range
    Dim qtResultRange As Range, TBL As String, URL As String
    Dim DES As String, COL As String, colsNo As Long, i As Long
    
    Set sourceSheet = Sheet6: colsNo = 6 'use here the number of columns to be processed
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    
    For i = 1 To colsNo
        Set rng = Sheet1.cells(1, i).Value
            
            For Each cel In rng.cells
                TBL = rng.cells(1)
                URL = rng.cells(2)
                DES = rng.cells(3)
                COL = rng.cells(4)
            Next cel
             
        With sourceSheet
            Set destCell = .Range(DES)
            On Error Resume Next
            .ListObjects(TBL).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        
        Set QT = destCell.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=destCell)
        
        With QT
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .WebFormatting = xlNone
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = COL
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .Refresh
            Set qtResultRange = .ResultRange
            .Delete
        End With
        
        With destCell
            .Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TBL
            sourceSheet.ListObjects(TBL).ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need for `rng` object. You can remove and use the `i` counter to reference `TBL`, `URL` etc. variables.

Comment: @Dean: The above code can be designed in many ways. Even using an array, but I only wanted to be clear form didactic point of view. I adapted his code in a way to be easily understood.

Comment: I'm getting an error when running it. `Compile error:

Statement invalid outside Type block`

Comment: Try the updated code, please. It was a typo there and ":" instead of ","... I couldn't test the code.

Comment: I get `Run-time error '424':

Object required`

Comment: @GreenSquirrel: On which line? What value has `i` variable when the code stops? Move the mouse cursor over i, to see its value...

Comment: There is only a pop-up with this error. I'm on office365 for Mac

Comment: @GreenSquirrel: It cannot be only a pop-up... Isn't it a yellow code line? Try running the code line by line, alternatively pressing F8 and see where the code stops.

Comment: I'm doing everything that I can, but F8 doesn't work in Office 365 for mac. And nothing is in yellow

Comment: @GreenSquirrel: I am not familiar with 'for MAC' applications, but do you press F8 **being in VBE (Visual Basic Editor)**?

Comment: Now, I must leave my office. If still something to te clarified, I will come back when I will be at home...

Answer (score 0):

I have found it! Finally.

Here's the working script. Maybe someone can use it in the future. Thank you all for the help.

```
    Sub ImportTBL1()
   
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim QT As QueryTable
    Dim destCell As Range
    Dim qtResultRange As Range
    Dim TBL As String
    Dim URL As String
    Dim DES As String
    Dim COL As String
   
    Set sourceSheet = Sheet6
    Dim rng As Range:
    
    'Loop through each used cell in row 1
    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    'Dim cel As Range
       
        'For Each cel In rng.Cells   'rng is only one cell. No need to loop through one cell
            TBL = rng.Cells(1, 1)
            URL = rng.Cells(2, 1)
            DES = rng.Cells(3, 1)
            COL = rng.Cells(4, 1)
        'Next cel
             
         With sourceSheet
             Set destCell = .Range(DES)
             On Error Resume Next
             .ListObjects(TBL).Delete
             On Error GoTo 0
         End With
        
         Set QT = destCell.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=destCell)
        
         With QT
             .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
             .WebFormatting = xlNone
             .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
             .WebTables = COL
             .BackgroundQuery = False
             .Refresh
             Set qtResultRange = .ResultRange
             .Delete
         End With
        
         With destCell
             .Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TBL
             sourceSheet.ListObjects(TBL).ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
         End With
         
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Well I delete this Dean and you can give the answer. Did you see my little extra?